# Logstash Grok Pattern for Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logstash-grok

Anyone have a Logstash pattern for Ruby on Rails 4 multiline logs?

I only have a pattern for Rails 3, which has a much different log structure:

```
RUUID \h{32}
# rails controller with action
RCONTROLLER (?<controller>[^#]+)#(?<action>\w+)
# this will often be the only line:
RAILS4HEAD (?m)Started %{WORD:verb} "%{URIPATHPARAM:request}" for % {IPORHOST:clientip} at (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}$
# for some a strange reason, params are stripped of {} - not sure that's a good idea.
RPROCESSING \W*Processing by %{RCONTROLLER} as (?<format>\S+)(?:\W*Parameters: {%{DATA:params}}\W*)?
RAILS4FOOT Completed %{NUMBER:response}%{DATA} in %{NUMBER:totalms}ms %{GREEDYDATA}
RAILS4PROFILE (?:\(Views: %{NUMBER:viewms}ms \| ActiveRecord: %{NUMBER:activerecordms}ms|\(ActiveRecord: %{NUMBER:activerecordms}ms)?
# putting it all together
RAILS4 %{RAILS4HEAD}(?:%{RPROCESSING})?(?<context>(?:%{DATA}\n)*)(?:%{RAILS4FOOT})?
```

Rails 4 logs are now in the format, which includes a timestamp and what looks like is an ID (#).

```
I, [2016-01-26T23:21:44.581108 #27447]  INFO -- : Started GET "/login" for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX at 2016-01-26 23:21:44 -0800
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot for a rails4 grok pattern, no hope.

I found some alternatives which i'm using now, they might be helpful for people having the same problem.

**Approach #1**

First, add the lograge gem to your application. this gem will simplify the rails log to something that you can parse easily using grok.

Then you can use the following pattern

```
LOGRAGE %{WORD:method}%{SPACE}%{DATA}%{SPACE}action=%{WORD:controller}#%{WORD:action}%{SPACE}status=%{INT:status}%{SPACE}duration=%{NUMBER:duration}%{SPACE}view=%{NUMBER:view}(%{SPACE}db=%{NUMBER:db})?%{GREEDYDATA}
```

This method was mentioned in this [article](http://www.morethanseven.net/2012/08/19/Tale-of-a-grok-pattern/).

**Approach #2**

As another alternative, you can use the json filter as in the following [article](https://manas.com.ar/blog/2015/12/15/logging-for-rails-apps-in-docker.html) with slightly different lograge configurations.

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "short_message"
    remove_field => "short_message"
  }
}
```